# Inverting $f:\mathbb{CP}^1\to\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

How would one invert the map $$f[z:w]=\left(\frac{\operatorname{Re}( w \bar{z})}{|w|^2 + |z|^2}, \frac{\operatorname{Im}(w\bar{z})}{|w|^2 + |z|^2},\frac{|w|^2-|z|^2}{|w|^2+|z|^2}\right)$$
of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ onto $\mathbb{S}^2$ to obtain $f^{-1}:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{CP}^1$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f[z:w] = (a,b,c)$. We have $$\left\vert \frac{w}{z} \right\vert^2 = \frac{1+c}{1-c}$$ and $$a+bi = \frac{w\overline{z}}{|w|^2 + |z|^2} = \frac{w/z}{|w/z|^2 + 1} \implies \frac{w}{z} = \frac{2(a+bi)}{1-c}$$

Hence $[z:w] = [1-c : 2(a+bi)]$.